# Object or function in module pattern OO JS?

Tags: javascript

Recently started writing modularised js and I'm starting to notice the numerous ways one can write them.

I know the core principles of when to use an object literal or function but whats the beneficiaries of writing a module as an object literal or function on a larger scale development? Portability, flexibilty, maintainability?

```
var filterOverlays = { ..code .. };

var filterOverlays = function() { ..code ..}
```

Call in another page:

```
$(document).ready(filterOverlays.init);

filterOverlays();
```

Comment: Imo it comes down to preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might worth reading about Javascript AMD leaning towards functions. It can provide useful input for your decision.

https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD

http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html